# Create array object in a class, ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have created two classes, Blog and Post, try to create an array of Post, in Blog, shows me the following error: "undefined method` push 'for {}: Hash "

How I can do to keep in the Array?

```
class Blog
    def initialize
        @post = {}
    end
    def addPost (newPost)
#Here I try to add an object blog, post an array of objects
        @post.push(newPost)
    end
end
class Post
    def initialize title, date, text
        @title = title
        @date = date
        @text = text
    end
    def printPost
        puts "#{@title} \n #{@date} \n ****************** \n #{@text}"
    end
end
myBlog = Blog.new
firstPost = Post.new("First Post", "21/12/2014", "This is my first post on my first blog")
secondPost = Post.new("Second Post", "11/10/2015", "This is my seocond post on my first blog")
myBlog.addPost(firstPost)
myBlog.addPost(secondPost)
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to create `Array`.. But you didn't give a small amount of time to read the Ruby Array API.. That's not good. :(

Comment: When reporting an exception that was raised, please give the offending line as well as all pertinent information in the exception message (though here it's obvious). Ruby newbies often don't give error messages the attention they deserve. In this case, it pinpoints the problem. You are invoking `push` on an instance of `Hash` (i.e, sending the method `push` to an instance of the class `Hash`). The error message says that the class `Hash` doesn't have an instance method `push`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the variable as an array, not as a hash.

```
@post = []
```

Comment: I just wrote same thing. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to Ruby.